# Using Darren Johnstone's Large File Upload Library with ASP.NET MVC Controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ajax, http, upload

Darren Johnstone wrote [a comprehensive server control and library](http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/15/aspnet-file-upload-module-version-2-beta-1/) to upload large files with a progress bar in ASP.NET.  I would like to use it with ASP.NET MVC, using a controller method to receive the file, and an Ajax controller method to drive the status bar.

I have studied the classes, but am having difficulty getting my mind around what the punch-in points are, and how it would be integrated into MVC.

Has anyone used this with MVC, withou using the server controls included with the library?  If so, how?  A simple code sample would be great.

NOTE:  I am willing to use a different upload library if it is better, especially if it uses a jQuery library for the progress bar, but it must NOT require a flash/silverlight dependency, and it does need to be faithful to the MVC style of coding.

Comment: Your link to http://darrenjohnstone.net/2008/07/15/aspnet-file-upload-module-version-2-beta-1/
is broken.  Do you have any other suggested path to this module?

Comment: @Steve: Alas, it appears that his entire web server has been secured behind a login. It might be a server configuration error; I would wait a couple of days and see if it gets fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a [demo MVC solution which uses an ASP.NET server control here](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/05/12/38297/). Not this control, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

An MVC implementation using SignalR for upload progress reporting can be found here http://blog.appsoftware.com/post/2013/03/08/ASPNET-File-Uploader-with-SignalR-Progress-Bar-and-Extended-HTTP-Request-Processing