# How to get the progress while uploading a file in C# ? And want to display it in JS

Tags: c#, extjs4

I'm using Ext JS 4.0 for all my layout and ASP.net C# for the server side.
I'm doing a multiple file upload.
I already have a progress bar for each file uploading in JS. But I don't have the progress value (So it's always 0%).
I need to know the progression and for which file.

I'm using `XMLHttpRequest` in JS, I get a `HttpPostedFileBase` in C# and use the `SaveAs(path)` method to save the file on the server.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4424143/731323. (XMLHttpRequest version 2 is required)

Comment: Are you sure this is the upload progress in the server and not in local from JS to C#?

Comment: No its client side (browser/xhr tracks the progress without quering the server). There is no file progress for uploads in ASP.Net by default. There was a file upload library from Darren Johnstone, but it's no longer available i think. Maybe this brings you a step forward http://stackoverflow.com/a/1432784/731323

Comment: I'm doing: `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (e) {me.getUploadStore().first().set('progress', e.position / e.totalSize);
                            me.getUploadStore().commitChanges();
                        });` But that's not working. The bar doesn't move.